# android: My software does not work in a linear manner

Tags: android

i have this code

```
TextView B = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMSG);
B.setText("Loading...");

Call_My_Func();

B.setText("");
```

my function `Call_My_Func()` work for 1 minute, but i can see the message **"Loading..."**

is there in java for android something like `Application.DoEvent()` like i use in C#  ?

Comment: So you SHOULD see loading because it sounds like you're saying your function blocks for a minute and you won't hit the second settext until it returns. Also you shouldn't block the ui thread for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the message because you're blocking the UI thread with that long running call (as you seem to know based on your DoEvent comment).

An easy way to move long running operations into another thread is Androids [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).